# React native firebase/admob iOS pod install problems

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-admob

i'm trying to install **@react-native-firebase/admob** with the following command:

```
npm install @react-native-firebase/admob
```

After that when i'm going in to ios folder on the project and using :

> - pod repo update
> - pod install

i'm getting the following error:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "Firebase/AdMob":   In Podfile:
> RNFBAdMob (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/admob`) was resolved to 11.5.0, which depends on
> Firebase/AdMob (= 8.8.0)
>
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency:
> `Firebase/AdMob (= 8.8.0)`.
>
> ```
> You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.  *
> ```
>
> mistyped the name or version.  * not added the source repo that hosts
> the Podspec to your Podfile.

Can somewone help me? i'm using:

- Node verison 14.17.6
- npm version 6.14.15
- CocoaPods 1.11.2
- platform ios '11.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite difficult to find a admob package that works with React native, but there are some ways. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67777679/basic-usage-of-react-native-firebase-admob-gives-typeerror-0-admob-defaul) can help you, try the instructions mentioned in the answers and make sure you install the correct packages.

Comment: Thanks i sovled my issue with setting the same verison of :

 "@react-native-firebase/admob": "11.5.0"
 "@react-native-firebase/app": "11.5.0"

Without "^" in my package.json and then running "npm install"